# Search a string's unknown text and replace it

Tags: python, regex

I want to search for a section of a string in a data file and replace it.

No problem doing it if the exact text in the section of interest is known, but I seem unable to do it if the exact text is not fully known.

The contents of the string(s) may be different (may be numbers or names or mixed).

The string(s) are read from a file, get replaced, and are written back to the file.

I tried many combinations of regular expression syntax and get close, but never what I need...

I want to replace any/all number-pairs in the section of interest with 0.0 0.0  (no comma)

**Example:**
*Results* for the code below are:

```
The Original String
(cat 5.34 8.763) kenneled in:

The Replaced String
(dog 0.0 0.0)5.34 8.763) kenneled in:
```

I want Replaced String to be:

```
(dog 0.0 0.0) kenneled in:
```

Here is my code attempt:

```
data    = '(cat 5.34 8.763) kenneled in:'  # Section of the String
pattern = '[(cat *? )]+'                 # test the String
repl    = '(dog 0.0 0.0)'              # replace it with this


print('The Original String')
print(data + '\n')

result = re.sub(pattern, repl, data, count=1)

print('The Replaced String')
print(result)
```

All was good until I selected a file containing multiple similar strings - these extra strings can be different / similar / identical and I *don't* want them changed.

The problem is: All the text/content gets deleted - all of the text (except the first string) gets deleted.

I added `count=1` but it didn't work...

```
data = re.sub(r"[^(]+ \d+\.?\d* \d+\.?\d*", "at 0.0 0.0", s1, count=1)
```

Example of the text I want to keep without being affected:

```
(hound (cat 3.34 5.67)
(hound (cat 3.37 1.67)
(hound (cat 9.85 4.3)
(puppy (cat 6.76 0.123)
```

Comment: Maybe review [the Stack Overflow `regex` tag info page](/tags/regex/info) which covers this and many other common beginner errors.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

IIUC, change the regular expression to ([regex101 demo](https://regex101.com/r/ifIWpA/2)):

```py
import re

s = "(cat 5.34 8.763) kenneled in:"


s = re.sub(r"[^(]+ \d+\.?\d* \d+\.?\d*", "dog 0.0 0.0", s)
print(s)
```

Prints:

```
(dog 0.0 0.0) kenneled in:
```

Comment: Thank you - Perfect answer and fast response!
And, thanks for the Link!

Comment: I added follow-up comment to the post about problem...

Comment: @headscratch I suggest to open a new question here on SO where you put what have you tried and whats not working.